# Android W/SoundPool: sample 0 not READY

Tags: java, android, soundpool

Buenas tengo un problema al reproducir el sonido con SoundPool en Android, quiero que cuando se pinche una imagen salga un sonido y al pinchar sobre la imagen me devuelve el error de que sample 0 not ready, si alguien sabe de que va el problema porque no encuentro una solución.

Muchas gracias

Aqui creo el metodo para inicializarlo:

```
   RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void inicializarSoundPool(){


            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes .Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .build();
            soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                    .setMaxStreams(10) // número máximo de streams
                    .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes) // atributos de audio previamente definidos
                    .build();


         mario_bros_1_up = soundPool.load(getContext(), R.raw.mario_bros_1_up, 1);
         mario_bross_firework = soundPool.load(getContext(), R.raw.mario_bros_firework, 1);
         mario_bross_hoo = soundPool.load(getContext(), R.raw.mario_bros_woo_hoo, 1);
         mario_coin = soundPool.load(getContext(), R.raw.mario_coin, 1);


    }
```

Aqui declaro una variable global de soundPool:

```
    private SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
```

Y aqui es donde llamo a los soundPool:

```
//REPRODUCIR SONIDO
        soundPool.play(mario_bros_1_up, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tratas de reproducir el sonido cuando aún no esta listo para reproducción, en este caso debes usar el listener [SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener) para determinar cuando esta listo y procedes a reproducir el sonido usando el método `play()`.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int mySoundId, int status) {
       
        //REPRODUCIR SONIDO
        soundPool.play(mario_bros_1_up, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);    
         
    }
});
```